# Syncing time with external Grandmaster Clock

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clock

I have a Grandmaster Clock with IP: 192.168.3.16 and I want my ubuntu (IP: 192.168.3.22) to sync with it using PTP.

I tried searching over internet to configure using ptp4l and pnc2sys. But, i am lost. I would be grateful if anyone could help me.